# Parameters of energy function for TSP

Tags: machine-learning, ne.neural-evol, tsp, statistical-physics

[This question was initially asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63489/parameters-of-energy-function-for-tsp). It went unanswered so I thought I should ask it in a different community.]

I am reading [this paper](http://www.genomics.princeton.edu/hopfield/PDFs/TSP.pdf) by Hopfield et al. On page six, the authors defined the energy function of the Traveling-Salesman-Problem (TSP) mapped onto an artificial neural network as follows:

$$E = \frac{A}{2} \sum_X \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i} V_{Xi} V_{Xj} + \frac{B}{2} \sum_i \sum_X \sum_{X\ne Y} V_{Xi} V_{Yi} + \frac{C}{2} (\sum_X \sum_i V_{Xi} - n)^2 + \frac{1}{2D} \sum_X \sum_{Y\ne X} \sum_i d_{XY} V_{Xi} (V_{Y, i+1} + V_{Y, i-1})$$

Here the first three terms maintain correctness of the function while the final term calculate actual distance of the tour. Later on page seven, the authors picked the values of A, B, C and D for simulation.

I don't understand on what basis they choose those values. Any help?

Comment: Pretty much arbitrarily.

Comment: @MCH If arbitrarily how can we use it for practical purposes?

Comment: When it comes to heuristics, we care more about whether things work rather than why.

Comment: @MCH, I am afraid I don't get it yet. Why didn't Hopfield just defined A, B and C to be 2's so that we could get rid of the fractions?

Comment: if you are taking derivatives of degree two polynomials it is useful to have $1/2$ to make computations simpler.

Comment: @Kaveh, when we implement this expression, do we take derivatives at any point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to choose the parameters A, B, C, D properly; 
as it is the case for most heuristics, the parameters are chosen ''by experience''. 
Worse, there is no guarantee that the solution (the array of the outputs) 
of this heuristic is indeed a feasible TSP tour!

In this context, perhaps interesting to read: Wilson and Pawley, 
[On the stability of the Travelling Salesman Problem 
algorithm of Hopfield and Tank](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00363956), 
Biological Cybernetics 58 (1988) 63-70.

To your first comment: I don't think that this TSP energy function is useful for practical purposes. 
If you want to solve TSP in practice, maybe [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/) 
is the right starting point.